# Centering a bootstrap table within an accordion panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time centering a table I've put inside a panel of an accordion slider on my website. The page I'm talking about is this: 
http://www.smartcuts.ch/index-TEST.html#latest

My html is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table summary="This table shows our rates" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
```

Can I center the table within the panel using some command in this html or must I use CSS? If so, please enlighten me. I've tried all kinds of stuff but nothing seems to work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems to work fine if you use `container-fluid` and `col-xs-12`.  `container` has fixed pixel widths depending on screen size, and `container-fluid` just fills the available width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- remove the `container`class or eventually use `.container-fluid`
- use `col-xs-12` instead of `col-xs-11`.

Here is the working code:

```
<div><!-- removed class .container -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table summary="This table shows our rates" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
           <!-- Table content here-->
        </table>

      </div><!--end of .table-responsive-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FINAL RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you all very much. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[image]You don't have to kill the container class, you can update it to .container-fluid. And you don't need to change .col-xs-11 to .col-xs-12.

You can add an ID to the .col-xs-11 div and override two styles to center the div instead of the table itself. I am assuming that you picked .col-xs-11 because you wanted that specific width, and since the table is responsive it's inheriting the width of the containing div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="center-table" class="col-xs-11">
             <div class="table-responsive">
```

CSS:

```
#center-table{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working JS fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/joeydehnert/oczyocwp

Comment: Your solution isn't correct. If you try opening the OP website in your browser devtools and adding your code the table isn't centered on mid size or large size screens. It has more margin on the left.

Comment: It does work, just needed to update .container to .container-fluid to account for padding coming from the .panel-body div on OP's site. Photo to prove it.